# Javascript Date selector

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I need the user to select his/her date of birth and I'm using javascript & php.

```
    var date_arr = new Array;
var days_arr = new Array;

date_arr[0]=new Option("January",31);
date_arr[1]=new Option("February",28);
date_arr[2]=new Option("March",31);
date_arr[3]=new Option("April",30);
date_arr[4]=new Option("May",31);
date_arr[5]=new Option("June",30);
date_arr[6]=new Option("July",31);
date_arr[7]=new Option("August",30);
date_arr[8]=new Option("September",30);
date_arr[9]=new Option("October",31);
date_arr[10]=new Option("November",31);
date_arr[11]=new Option("December",30);

function fill_select(f)
{
        document.writeln("<SELECT name=\"months\"               onchange=\"update_days(FRM)\">");
        for(x=0;x<12;x++)
                document.writeln("<OPTION value=\""+date_arr[x].value+"\">"+date_arr[x].text);
        document.writeln("</SELECT><SELECT name=\"days\"></SELECT>");
        selection=f.months[f.months.selectedIndex].value;
}

function update_days(f)
{
        temp=f.days.selectedIndex;
        for(x=days_arr.length;x>0;x--)
        {
                days_arr[x]=null;
                f.days.options[x]=null;
         }
        selection=parseInt(f.months[f.months.selectedIndex].value);
        ret_val = 0;
        if(f.months[f.months.selectedIndex].value == 28)
        {
                year=parseInt(f.years.options[f.years.selectedIndex].value);
                if (year % 4 != 0 || year % 100 == 0 ) ret_val=0;
                else
                        if (year % 400 == 0)  ret_val=1;
                        else
                                ret_val=1;
        }
        selection = selection + ret_val;
        for(x=1;x < selection+1;x++)

        {
                days_arr[x-1]=new Option(x);
                f.days.options[x-1]=days_arr[x-1];
        }
        if (temp == -1) f.days.options[0].selected=true;
        else
             f.days.options[temp].selected=true;
}
function year_install(f)
{
        document.writeln("<SELECT name=\"years\" onchange=\"update_days(FRM)\">")
        for(x=1950;x<2005;x++) document.writeln("<OPTION value=\""+x+"\">"+x);
        document.writeln("</SELECT>");
        update_days(f)
}
```

This is the generating code:

```
<script>fill_select(document.frmProfile);year_install(document.frmProfile)</script>
```

The problem is when its submitted to the database the day and year are sent according to selection but the month displays the total num of days in that month instead of the month itself.

Eg:-- If i want to select february 20 1996 I want to get an output 1996-02-20 to enter into db.
Using this code I get an output as  1996-28-20
I know the problem is in this function

```
function fill_select(f)
    {
            document.writeln("<SELECT name=\"months\"               onchange=\"update_days(FRM)\">");
            for(x=0;x<12;x++)
                    document.writeln("<OPTION value=\""+date_arr[x].value+"\">"+date_arr[x].text);
            document.writeln("</SELECT><SELECT name=\"days\"></SELECT>");
            selection=f.months[f.months.selectedIndex].value;
    }
```

But I just don't know what exactly I should change

Comment: use firebug or a debugger or a dom viewer to see what is the value inside your options when the page renders

Comment: In firebug :-

<option value="31">January </option>
<option value="28">February </option>
<option value="31">March </option>

The Months are using the total num of months as the value>
But i dont know how to change this in the code. Plz help

for(x=0;x<12;x++)
                document.writeln("<OPTION value=\""+date_arr[x].value+"\">"+date_arr[x].text);
        document.writeln("</SELECT><SELECT name=\"days\"></SELECT>");
        selection=f.months[f.months.selectedIndex].value;

Comment: press the edit button on your question and add a sample of the format that you want your code to generate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to safe yourself from the hassle of calculating the leap years and all, and use [the jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) instead.

Because the value of the options are used when you hit 'submit', you do not want the month values to contain their number of days (28, 30, 31), but their actual number instead (1-12).

So change

```
for(x=0;x<12;x++)
    document.writeln("<OPTION value=\""+date_arr[x].value+"\">"+date_arr[x].text);
```

...into ...

```
for(x=0;x<12;x++)
    document.writeln("<OPTION value=\""+(x+1)+"\">"+date_arr[x].text);
```

Now we cannot rely on these values anymore to determine how many days are in a month, but we can use the `date_arr` for that. So change:

```
selection=parseInt(f.months[f.months.selectedIndex].value);
ret_val = 0;
if(f.months[f.months.selectedIndex].value == 28)
{ // (...)
```

... into ...

```
selection=parseInt(date_arr[f.months.selectedIndex].value);
ret_val = 0;
if(selection == 28)
{ // (...)
```

Now it should work better. Good luck.

Comment: Thank you so much michel404. It worked .
I did check out the jQuery UI datepicker, really cool.